# How to get some default configured information of Firefox?

Tags: c++, windows, firefox, zip, zlib

My program needs to get some default configured information of Firefox. I do this by read those information in some file which in omni.jar file (C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\omni.jar, omni.jar for old Firefox versions: 4-9, omni.ja for later Firefox version: 10, 11).

omni file is just a zip file format. I used MiniZip library to read zip file. With later versions (omni.ja), it's ok. But failed with older version (omni.jar).

Now, the solutions for me are two ways: try to fix MiniZip read omni.jar file ok. Or, get those default information without uses MiniZip or read omni.jar file. I can't with both.

Some default information I need to read, ex: browser.search.defaultenginename, ...
My program is a standalone, run on win xp, win 7.

Can you help me, plz?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can get firefox default configuration information by typing about:config in url bar.